# Citrix GUI in C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, citrix

I have been looking for a way to create a simple GUI for users to stop,start,create, list running VMs in Citrix XenServer. I will create a form that has input boxes for users to put the name of the vm in, then a button to do the wanted task for that name. I would will also create a list box that will list all VM's and another that will list all running VM's. The same for all paused VM's and so on. my biggest issue is I cant find a way to run the command on the remote linux system then list the output into the area I want. 
They do have Citrix XenCenter but I am wanting a GUI that will give the users limited functionality.

Comment: No offense, but given your other questions in which you ask about pretty basic programming concepts, are you sure you want to embark on a real project so soon? It’s a bit like wanting to play a Mozart sonata after just one or two piano lessons.

Comment: I completely agree. I thought it could just be work in progress. Its something that if it took me several months to do it certainly wouldnt be an issue.

Comment: I don't have an answer to this question, but rather than have an input box, why not just make a single drop down box with all the server names... you could "Color" the running servers.  By using the user-selected item in a ddbox, it prevents you from having to verify if the user input the name correctly.

Comment: I am looking for something that will just allow me to code a buttonclick to exicute a command on the XenServer box.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this question was asked some time ago, but I'll post the answer anyway. All the 
Citrix XenServer operations can be performed via XML RPC. Download the XenServer SDK, it has code samples to get you started.
Moreover, SDK also provides .NET bindings, http://docs.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/5.6.0fp1/1.0/en_gb/sdk.html#language_bindings-c-sharp, which means you won't have to make the XML RPC calls yourself.